# Assembly.LoadFrom fails on a cpp/CLI DLL with MFC includes

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a C# application that dynamically loads other dlls using `Assembly.LoadFrom`.
This method fails if the dll is a managed cpp with MFC support and any includes such `afxwin.h`.

To reproduce this behaviour you simply create a new managed cpp dll with the wizard. Add the MFC support flag into configuration. Until you do not put any of the MFC standard includes in the `stdafx.h` file, `Assembly.LoadFrom` does not fail. If you put `#include "afxwin.h"` in the `stdafx.h` file, `Assembly.LoadFrom` fails! (i.e. the dll is empty!)

Any clues???

Thanks,
Cabbi

Comment: +1 for NOT using the assembly tag. :)

Comment: LoadFrom() is pretty likely to fail for mixed-mode assemblies that have a dependency on an unmanaged DLL.  Windows won't have much of a chance to find such a DLL since it is not likely to be stored in the same directory as the EXE nor on the PATH.  An *empty* DLL sounds like a very unlikely scenario.

Comment: the assemblies are all in the same directory. The empty dll without #include "afxwin.h" loads well, adding that include and nothing else let the load fail.

Comment: @Devolus: mov ebx, reputation; inc ebx; :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing as you described in visual studio 2010.

I set the project settings to Use MFC as a shared DLL, and included afxwin.h in stdafx.h.
I successfully invoked AfxMessageBox(). So it cannot be the fact that you use MFC, it has to be something else.

I suppose you use MFC as a shared DLL? Also, please write your full exception details.
Use Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to check what DLLs your app tries to load. Maybe that will reveal potentially missing DLLs (like the MFC runtime). Use Dependency Walker (depends.exe) to see what DLLs your mixed mode library is referring to.

Also, if you happen to use boost::thread statically linked, this will cause loading of the mixed mode assembly to fail.